# Text wont appear on my wpf status bar

Tags: wpf

I'm not sure what could be wrong here. The panel shows up where I want it, but it doesn't want to show me text no matter what I do.

```
<StatusBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF807E7E" FontFamily="Lucida Sans"  >
        <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>

        <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Text="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX" ></TextBlock>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
```

Comment: I did that, too, it was originally a ViewBox with a TextBlock. This is the result of me stripping things down trying to find the issue.

Comment: Set the Height to a value that doesn't hide the content. `Height="25"` for example. Or don't set the Height at all.

Answer (score 2):

Delete `Height="5"` or increase this value and everything will be as expected.

Of course, if you want to keep this height, you can use a ViewBox.

```
<StatusBarItem Padding="0">
     <Viewbox>
         <TextBlock Text="XXXXXXXXXXXX" Background="Blue" />
     </Viewbox>
</StatusBarItem>
```

Comment: Ha. Beat ya by 40 seconds. In a comment, though.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment, or I would stop writing.

Comment: Ah that's silly of me. On the ViewBox, how do I align the top of it with the top of the statusbar if I want to keep the size? This is my first foray into WPF and I feel so silly sometimes.

Comment: Nevermind, added VerticalAlign="Top" and padding 0 to the TextBox. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you could find a way. However, I updated the answer for the ViewBox case.